# How do you update the div with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, random, var

In my class we have started to learn how to use React, and I'm having a little trouble with one of the starter projects. I just need to press a button and have that number appear on the page, a very basic sim of a die roll. I can do this in the console but I can't figure out how to push the variable onto the page.

The code for the App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './Diceroll';
import Diceroll from './Diceroll';

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
             <Diceroll />

        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my Diceroll.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Diceroll extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={() => {this.dieroll()}}>Roll the 120 Die</button>


      </div>
    )
  }

dieroll() {
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 121);

    console.log(roll);
 }
}

export default Diceroll;
```

Yes, the die roll is supposed to be from 1 to 120. We looked up the die with the most sides on it an the first result was a die with 120 sides.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with math.

Comment: The main function to "roll the dice" is a Math.random(), and the question was how to take the result of that random number and put it on the screen for a user to see.

Comment: That's just calling a function.  The person that wrote the method had to understand the math behind the Knuth algorithm, but you don't.  I understood what it was for.  I'm questioning the need for that tag on your question, that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update `Diceroll.js` code below code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Diceroll extends Component {
  state = {
    roll: 0
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.dieroll();
          }}
        >
          Roll the 120 Die
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.state.roll}
      </div>
    );
  }

  dieroll() {
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 121);
    this.setState({ roll: roll });
    console.log(roll);
  }
}

export default Diceroll;
```

You can make use of `state`, using `setState` you can update and show updated `roll` number. [click here to learn more about state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```js
class Diceroll extends React.Component {

  state = {
    roll: 0
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      button onClick = {
        () => {
          this.dieroll()
        }
      } > Roll the 120 Die < /button> <
      br / > < br / > {
        this.state.roll
      } <
      /div>
    )
  }

  dieroll() {
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 121);
    this.setState({
      roll: roll
    });
    console.log(roll);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      Diceroll / >

      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```